# Combine 2 list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
x = [a,b]

y = [c,d]
```

and I want to create a list of dictionary like this:

```
dict = [{ex1:a,ex2:c},{ex1:b,ex2:c},{ex1:a,ex2:d},{ex1:b,ex2:d}]
```

How can I do that in a simple way?

Comment: Could you please post the code you've tried as well as clarify your objective? Stack Overflow does not simply code for you.

Comment: I guess you have your answer now so I'll just point out that using `dict`, which is a builtin, as a variable name is not good practice and can cause problems elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it using a *list comprehension*:

```
lst = [{'ex1': j, 'ex2': i} for i in y for j in x]
```

If the list items are strings, you'll get:

```
print(lst)
# [{'ex2': 'c', 'ex1': 'a'}, {'ex2': 'c', 'ex1': 'b'}, {'ex2': 'd', 'ex1': 'a'}, {'ex2': 'd', 'ex1': 'b'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a package called `itertools` which provides many methods to make this kind of things easy. I assume you might have not only one list, but eventually more, so you can put them in another list `my_lists`, take their product, and the rest of the thing is just making it a `dict` in the desired format, i.e. with keys like `ex1`.

**Edit:**

Here is the same with list comprehension:

```
[dict(('ex%u' % (i[0] + 1), i[1]) for i in enumerate(co))
    for co in itertools.product(*my_lists)]
```

And was like this with map:

```
import itertools

x = ['a', 'b']
y = ['c', 'd']
my_lists = [x, y]

list_of_dicts = (
    list(
        map(
            lambda co:
                dict(
                    map(
                        lambda i:
                            ('ex%u' % (i[0] + 1), i[1]),
                        enumerate(co)
                    )
                ),
            itertools.product(*my_lists)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: your formatting is unconventional and makes this code almost impossible to read.

Comment: Please at least *try* to stick to Python style conventions. In Python, a comprehension is *almost always* better than an equivalent `map` with `lambda` from a readability perspective, and will likely perform better too. For the record, I did not downvote, since this does add a valuable generalization with `product`... just improve the style...

Comment: thanks Paul for pointing this out. I thought about it a lot how to format multiple nested maps, and this was the most clear I could come up with. but I would be extremely grateful if you could show me a better way (just put this in a pastebin, if you have 2 minutes for me)

Comment: The answer is *don't use multiple maps*.

Comment: Also just use string literals `'ex1'` and `'ex2'` rather than trying to be clever with `enumerate`.

Comment: I had a go at formatting it but really, it still didn't read very well for me. Consider the answer from Moses: `lst = [{'ex1': j, 'ex2': i} for i in y for j in x]`. There is no logical way to order your code under PEP 8 because the approach doesn't make sense when you can achieve the same goal with something like that.

Comment: So, with comprehensions, it's much easier to decipher what's going on:

`[{'ex'+str(i+1):v for i,v in enumerate(vals)} for vals in itertools.product(*my_lists)]`

Comment: Really, you should do something like `values = itertools.product(*my_lists)` then use the second argument to enumerate: `[{'ex%d'%i:v for i,v in enumerate(vals, 1)} for vals in values]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if you need that, seems like the OP doesnt and in the answer above leads to an extra level of indirection. I can see though that your example achieves it in a much clearer way.